# Will I ever have to uninstall windows 8?

Tags: windows-8-preview

If I've installed the consumer preview and would like to keep Windows 8 as my main operating system, will I ever have to uninstall it or purchase it in the future?

Comment: [The evaluation end date for this Consumer Preview is: 1/15/2013](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/how-long-i-can-use-windows-8-consumer-preview/9c28cc28-9cf3-4f1e-8282-f4ffcd66b3ad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. According to [this](http://betanews.com/2012/07/04/four-things-you-really-need-to-know-about-windows-8-upgrades/) site: "Previous beta versions of Windows 8, like the Developer Preview or Consumer Preview, can not be upgraded" to the full version.